# Modular arithmetic and functions

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

> Let $f(x) = (x^2-13)(x^2-17)(x^2-221)$. For $n=2,3,5,7$ show there exists $x\in\mathbb Z$ such that $f(x) \equiv 0\pmod n$.

I am aware that this means that $f(x)$ is divisible by $n$ but am unsure how to go about this question. Do I expand the brackets? If so, then what?

Comment: Sorry about see-sawing between elem.NT and NT-tags. I guess this could be seen as an exercise about quadratic residues, which may lift it to NT?

Comment: Don't expand! Just reduce the factors modulo $n$. For example modulo $n=5$ you get $f(x)=(x^2-3)(x^2-2)(x^2-1)$. Can you make the value of this zero mod five? Hint: Works for only one of the three factors (which is why it is better not to expand).

Comment: Note that $221= 13 \cdot 17$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what do you mean when you say it only works for one of the three factors? Surely the product of the three brackets have to = 0mod5 ? 

edit - is it because if you multiply anything by a multiple of 5 it is automatically divisible by 5?

Comment: Tommy, because $5$ is a prime, the product is divisible by five if and only if one of the factors is. This time only one of the factors can be divisible by five, but that is coincidental. For each choice of  those $n$ you can always make at least one of the factors divisible by it. With $n=2$, any factor will work, with $n=3,5,7$ only one factor will work. Your job is to show that by a clever choice of $x$ you can make that one factor divisible by $n$. Hint: you never need to test other values than $x=0,1,2,3,4,\ldots,n-1$. Anyway, you got it. A multiplying a multiple by 5 will give another.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

This is true for all $n$ prime because if $13$ and $17$ are not quadratic residues mod $n$ then $221= 13 \cdot 17$ is a quadratic residue mod $n$. This follows from [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).